# Sticky footer at the bottom

Tags: css, html, sticky-footer

I'm having trouble with my footer, it's not being pushed by the content, I already tried to substitute absolute to relative, but with no success, I'm trying to use bottom:0; but it's not working either, here is my css code:

```
html, body {


width:100%;
min-height:100%;
background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat;

}   

* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
a, img {
border:none;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
 }






#wrapper {
width: 1024px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
min-height: 100%;
position:relative;  
}


#foot {
width: 100%;
height:200px
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
background-image:url(../img/foot.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;


}




#banner {
min-height: 100%;
margin:0;
 padding:0;
position: relative;
top: 24px;
background-image: url(../img/banner2.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:173px;

}


#navigation {
height: 60px;
position: relative;
left: auto;
width: 100%;
top: 23px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
z-index:1;
border: none;   
}

#categoria {
position: absolute;
width: 710px;
height: 240px;
z-index: 0;
left: -29px;
top:30px;
padding: 0px;
z-index:1;



}

.othergames{
position: absolute;
top: -13px;
width: 740px;
height: 251px;
background-image: url(../img/otherg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index:1;
left: -43px;


}

.othergames-back{
position: absolute;
top: -11px;
width: 730px;
height: 247px;
background-color:#FFF;
left: -37px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;

}


#texto{
height: 10px;
text-align:center;
width: 50px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
left: 34px;
top: 243px;
}

#apDiv1 {
position: absolute;
left: -3px;
top: 3px;
width: 209px;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#like {
position: relative;
left: -3px;
top: 550px;
width: 215px;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}



#apDiv2 {
position: absolute;
left: 220px;
top: 60px;
width: 862px;
height: 482px;
z-index: 0;
padding: 0px;

}

#apDiv4 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
left: -6px;
top: 90px;
width: 201px;
height: 499px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

And the html code:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="banner"></div>

 <div id="navigation">








<div id="apDiv4">






 </div>



 <div id="fb-root"></div>

<div id="like">
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Legend-of-Games/476628629090111" data-width="215" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false" data-header="false"></div></div>



<div id="apDiv2">



   <script>
 (function($){
      $(window).load(function(){
        $("#apDiv2").mCustomScrollbar();


    });
 })(jQuery);
</script>

<div align="center" id="thumb">

<div id="screen_game">
```

```
<a href="legendofgames/gameview.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_GameData['idGames']; ?>">  <img style="border-radius:5px;border:thin solid #FFF;" src="../legendofgames/documentos/games/<?php echo $row_GameData['strImage']; ?>"  width="160" height="130"/></a>
<div align="center" id="gametext"><?php echo $row_GameData['strNome']; ?> </div>
</div>


</div>

<div id="apDiv1"><img src="../img/lateralb2.png" width="209" height="592"/>  



</div> 

</div>
</div>


<footer >
<div id="foot"></div>

</footer>

</body>
```

Comment: all the images you gave us are relative to your root directory, and we don't have that. Do you have this online with a website we can access?

Comment: why do you need the images? you have the sizes

Comment: Because otherwise the page is blank (http://jsfiddle.net/3ZLLu/), and did you have any JavaScript, because there is no text on the page.

Comment: instead of image use background-color:#FFF; I don't have the images uploaded online.

Comment: I dont see the problem i clicked on the links u posted below and it looks like the footer is on the bottom?

Comment: I didn't want the footer showing up at the middle of the page and the people having to scroll down to see the content, but that's a solution

Comment: thank you for your tips, I'll change the layout.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: No, Grant Weiss the problem was solved, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your position to fixed.

```
#foot {
width: 100%;
height:200px
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
background-image:url(../img/foot.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I can't test your code but I was able to get a sticky footer using a similar styling.

Comment: the problem is that the footer stays in the middle of the page, it's not going down, even with position fixed.

Comment: Try moving the foot div outside of the footer element. It's possible you have some other stylings applied that are affecting the foot div. Also, your foot.png image might not fit inside the div which may cause it to display in the middle of the page. For example, replace the background-image with just background: #000 and you should see a sticky black footer. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZLLu/1/

Comment: can you see what's happening?

Comment: I lost enough time with this so, that will be the answer, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Since you had some background images and content that weren't available, I generated and inserted some into a `<section>` with an ID of `container`. As you can see in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/3ZLLu/12/), I have just set up the footer as a fixed position block element at `bottom: 0;`, which means that it will always be at the bottom.

CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
}
```

Have fun with the rest of the page!

Comment: it didn't work, I set the position fixed like you said and here's the problem postimg.org/image/rl1vk65a5 postimg.org/image/ugeyr19a5

Comment: but I lost enough time with this so, that will be the answer, thank you